# Cannot get the JSON data returned from fetch API call to an array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to use custom hook to fetch a JSON from an API call to get an array of products. But it seems the data fetched from the API call is undefined, Can somebody clarify me what is wrong here.

I have attached the actual JSON data for the fetch URL as an image and the code and the returned error pane as an image. Helps would be very much appreciated.

**This is my useFetch.js file**

```
const baseUrl = "http://localhost:3001/";

export default function useFetch(url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${baseUrl}${url}`)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, [url]);

  return [data, error, loading];
}
```

**This is my App.jsx code**

```
import useFetch from "./services/useFetch";

export default function App() {
  const [size, setSize] = useState("");
  const { data: products, error, loading } = useFetch(
    "products?category=shoes"
  );

  const filteredProducts = size
    ? products.filter((element) =>
        element.skus.find(
          (element_skus) => element_skus.size === parseInt(size)
        )
      )
    : products;

  function renderProduct(p) {
    return (
      <div key={p.id} className="product">
        <a href="/">
          <img src={`/images/${p.image}`} alt={p.name} />
          <h3>{p.name}</h3>
          <p>${p.price}</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }

  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="content">
        <Header />
        <main>
          <section id="filters">
            <label htmlFor="size">Filter by Size:</label>{" "}
            <select
              id="size"
              value={size}
              onChange={(e) => setSize(e.target.value)}
            >
              <option value="">All sizes</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
            </select>
            {
              size && <h2>Found {filteredProducts.length} Items</h2>
            }
          </section>
          <section id="products">{filteredProducts.map(renderProduct)}</section>
        </main>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

**This is the JSON data image**
[image: JSON data from the URL]

**This is the Error image**
[image: Error pane]

Comment: `useEffect` hook is called _after_ the initial render. So, on the initial render, `products` is `null` and you call `.map()` method on the `null` value. Initial value of `data` in `useFetch` hook should be an empty array.

Comment: Your ```useFetch``` Hook is returning array but you are trying to destructure as object. either return ```{data, error, loading}``` or do this ```const [ data, error, loading ] = useFetch()```

Comment: Try changing only this code: filteredProducts?.map
This will avoid calling map function in an undefined variable.

Comment: @Yousaf Hi, thanks for the response, but even setting initial value to empty array throws the same error. can I implement this with useEffect hook then.

Comment: @DipankarMaikap Thank you. I got it now.